# Removing extra \n from a string in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-tesseract

I've been learning Text recognition in python recently. When converting images to string it outputs an extra newline randomly in my images. I've tried removing it but cant seem to find a way how. My goal is to separate the choices into its corresponding strings

Here is my code and image  :

[image: ROI_0.png]

```py
choices = cv2.imread("ROI_0.png", 0)
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
c = pytesseract.image_to_string(choices, config=custom_config, lang='eng')

print(c.rstrip("\n"))  # my attempt
text = repr(c)
print(text)
newtext = text.split("\\n")
print(newtext)
```

Here is the outputs:

```
a. E. 0. 125

b. R. A. 3846
c. R. A. 3396
d. R. A. 7925


'a. E. 0. 125\n\nb. R. A. 3846\nc. R. A. 3396\nd. R. A. 7925'

["'a. E. 0. 125", '', 'b. R. A. 3846', 'c. R. A. 3396', "d. R. A. 7925'"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is remove multiple new lines to a single new line:

```
import re

x = re.sub(r'\n{2, 10}', '\n', c)   # \n is new line, {2,10} is the range of occurrences of the newline that I'm searching for.
```

So it would be like:

```
choices = cv2.imread("ROI_0.png", 0)
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
c = pytesseract.image_to_string(choices, config=custom_config, lang='eng')

x = re.sub(r'\n{2, 10}', '\n', c)

print(x.rstrip("\n"))
```

Comment: Thank so much what worked for me is 
x = re.sub(r'\n{2}', '\n', c)